# Django multilingual site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create a multilingual website, which would get content from DB based on selected language. For that I use `i18n_patterns` and so I can get the selected language easily using `get_language()` in the view.

Right now, my models look like this (simplified):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField("Author", max_length=255)

class ArticleText(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    en = models.TextField("English")
    fr = models.TextField("French")
```

My idea (based on research here on SO) was that I would store the article's text content elsewhere, linking it's primary key to the actual `Article` object's primary key.

The `Article` model contains just general info (publish date, author, etc.), which is the same for all languages. However, I am not really sure how to access the data from my template. Right now I use:

```
context["articles"] = models.Content.objects.select_related("id")
```

I can then access the various fields in my template using

```
{% for article in articles %}
<h3>{{ article.author }} - {{ article.fr }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I want the language (`{{ article.$LANGUAGE }}`) to change based on the selected language. Something like

```
{{ article.$get_current_language }}  --> {{ article.fr }}
```

I guess I could do the following in the template:

```
{% if get_current_language == en %}
    {{ article.en }}
{% elif get_current_language == fr %}
    {{ article.fr }}
{% endif %}
```

But I think it's ugly to do this in the template - I'd rather do this in the view and just pass it into to the template. Unfortunately, I don't have any idea on how to pass all the article objects and their relative texts in the correct language, and in a way that I would be able to for-loop through them.

Am I overthinking things and should I just use the if-block in the template, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There are various packages which can deal with translation of database objects, take a look at https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation or https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a good use case for writing a custom template filter which will return the appropriate article version given the current language.

For detailed code explanation about how you can write a custom filter, see Django docs: [Writing custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).

And here's a code sample to get you started:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def localize(value, arg):
    """Returns appropriate language version 
    of the given article.

    value: the article
    arg: the current language code
    """

    article = value
    lang = arg

    try:
        # `getattr` will call `article.en` or `article.fr`
        # depending on the value of `lang`
        text = getattr(article, lang)
    except AttributeError:
        # if this code runs, this means that 
        # the `article` doesn't have a version
        # for the given `lang`

        # so, return a default version
        text = article.en

    return text
```

Now, you need to create a directory called `templatetags` inside your app and create a file in the directory and put this code in that file. The detailed instructions can be found in the [Code layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) section of the docs.

---

When you've read the docs about where to put the above code, this is how you can use this filter:

```
{% get_current_language as LANG %}

{{ article|localize:LANG }}
```